# Why is JS not running in my book

Tags: javascript, html, epub

Recently, I'm trying to convert "Web Project" into "epub".

Before that, I have a simple test as following.

I made a simple HTML file that prints "Hello World" and JavaScript changes the font color.

I convert this HTML file into epub format by Calibre converter.

However, I checked that JavaScript is not working on ePub viewer.

Is there an any way to enable Javascript to work properly after it converted to ePub ?

Comment: ["It is important to note, however, that scripting support is optional for Reading Systems and may be disabled for security reasons."](http://www.idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-overview.html#sec-scripting)

Comment: Not every device is able to run javascript. If you haven an iPad or Mac u can use the iBooks app. So what device u are using?

Comment: I have an android tablet "Galaxy Note 10.1". Thanks for your comment

Comment: I disagree that this question is too broad (although it did originally contain some "too broad" components, and the title did not reflect the actual question, which also made it seem too broad). The specific question is "why is JS not running in my book", which is a useful and valid question and has valid answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check that your manifest's entry for the XHTML pages on which scripting is used contain the `scripted` attribute.

You should check that your reader (Galazy Note 10.1 is a piece of hardware, not a reader), I mean the application you are using to read the book, supports scripting, as commenters have mentioned. Modern ones will. You could try Himawari, or Azardi.

Your font color changes may or may not be handled correctly, since various readers may override this in various ways.

Just out of curiosity, what do you mean by "printing"? On the off chance that you are using `document.write`, don't.

You can check that JavaScript is working in your book by checking that whatever you are doing in JavaScript is actually happening. There is no equivalent of a developer console or debugger.